# using wildcard on flask-wtf form fields in flask

Tags: python, flask, wildcard, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have been working on building a questionnaire using flask-wtf. my questions has 30 questions and
will likely grow in the future.

From reading the flask-wtf documentation. I see that to the **inputted data** from a form is accessible like so "**form.username.dat**a".

```
username = StringField('Username')

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        user = User(form.username.data)

        db_session.add(user)
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

**My question:**

my qusetionair form has many fields and would be illogical to have to enter form.FIELDNAME.data to get the inputted data for every field. i understand for a user registration form that it would be acceptable as there are only about 3-5 fields. However in my scenario (questionair form) this is not ideal

**Solution i tried:**

I named my fields question_1 question_2 qusetion_3 , then created a while look like below to dynamically enter the field name. however, flask-wtf complains "AttributeError: 'MyForm' object has no attribute 'question'"

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    string = 'q'
    for i in range(30): 
        question = "q"+str(i)
        field_name = form.question.data
        answer_to_add = Answer(answers=field_name) 
        db.session.add(answer_to_add)
        db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Can you post code related to `MyForm`?, it seems you are trying to access an attribute named `question` that does not belong to `MyForm`

Comment: If you want to read through all the fields on your form, perhaps your for loop should be: for field in form.data:  (haven't tried this myself but it appears to make sense from the WTForms documentation - https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/forms/?highlight=form#wtforms.form.Form.data).

Comment: @ben you're a legend. thanks that worked. not sure how i missed that

Comment: Thanks! Given that, could you expand your answer a little (maybe a few lines of code and link to the documentation) and then mark it as the correct answer? This will make it easier for folks to use in the future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

For people in the future who run into a similiar issue. The resolution is to simply use "form.data" and not specify a field as this will mean all fields are sent.

Code example:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
   answer = form.data
   "do something"
```

You can find more useful info in the docs: https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/forms/?highlight=form#wtforms.form.Form.data